# Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'emulator-5554! error

Tags: android

I am trying to write HelloWorld program in android. But getting error:

```
[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] Performing com.android.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-09-18 21:24:08 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-18 21:24:11 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2014-09-18 21:26:32 - HelloWorld] Failed to install HelloWorld.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-09-18 21:26:32 - HelloWorld] (null)
[2014-09-18 21:26:33 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: With another AVD, I am getting:[2014-09-18 22:08:27 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'chaks' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-18 22:08:27 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-18 22:08:30 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2014-09-18 22:09:05 - HelloWorld] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-18 22:09:05 - HelloWorld] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-18 22:09:07 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!

Comment: You should do what the console told you: `Please check logcat output for more details.` Something is logged there?

Answer (score 0):

[2014-09-18 21:23:57 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.

Check which version of android your application is being compiled and select the correct version. :)
[Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Comment: it had prompted AVD manager window to select AVD. I then selected AVD. After that as you can see, it was trying to installing apk. Then it failed.

Comment: try this:
Right Click ON PROJECT--->Run As---->Run Configurations.. there in Target tab select Manual.. now Click Run then you will be showed with a list of emulators and connected devices.. from which you can choose..

Comment: Next time I did that. It selected AVD: [2014-09-18 22:08:27 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'chaks' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'..                                           I am getting error: [2014-09-18 22:08:27 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-09-18 22:08:30 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...
[2014-09-18 22:09:05 - HelloWorld] Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-09-18 22:09:05 - HelloWorld] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-09-18 22:09:07 - HelloWorld] Launch canceled!